# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 with QNetworkReply

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkreply

I keep getting the following error:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "checkinapp::myOnFinishedSlot(QNetworkReply*)", referenced from: "checkinapp::qt_static_metacall(QObject*,QMetaObject::Call,int,void**) in moc_checkinapp.o

I have looked through several times and can't figure out where I have gone wrong. (Im new to c++ so im sorry i probably missed something obvious). Any help is appreciated :)

Here is my class:

```
class checkinapp : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    checkinapp(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~checkinapp();
    void databasehandler(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    int stressed;
    int happy;
    int hungry;
    int tired;
    int gender;
    bool help;
    int grade;
    bool submitted;
    void post()
    {
        m_networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager ( this );
        QVariantMap newUser;
        newUser[ "Stress" ] = QString::number(stressed);
        newUser[ "Sleep" ] = QString::number(tired);
        newUser[ "Hungry" ] = QString::number(hungry);
        newUser[ "Happy" ] = QString::number(happy);
        newUser[ "Grade" ] = QString::number(grade);
        newUser[ "Date" ] = "1/10/21";
        newUser[ "Gender" ] = QString::number(gender);
        newUser[ "Aid" ] = QString::number(help);
        QJsonDocument jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromVariant( newUser );
        QNetworkRequest newUserRequest( QUrl( "url/User.jason"));
        newUserRequest.setHeader( QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QString( "application/json" ));

        connect(m_networkManager, &QNetworkManager::finished, this, &checkinapp::myOnFinishSlot); // the error is here 

        m_networkManager->post( newUserRequest, jsonDoc.toJson() );
    }
    void exit()
    {
        QApplication::quit();
    }

public slots:
    void myOnFinishSlot(QNetworkReply* x) { exit(); } 
private slots:

    void on_happy_valueChanged(int value);

    void on_hungry_valueChanged(int value);

    void on_sleep_valueChanged(int value);

    void on_stress_valueChanged(int value);

    void on_male_toggled(bool checked);

    void on_female_toggled(bool checked);

    void on_other_toggled(bool checked);

    void on_help_toggled(bool checked);

    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::checkinapp *ui;
    QNetworkAccessManager * m_networkManager;
    QNetworkReply * m_networkReply;
};
```

Comment: in the code you posted the method is indeed not defined. Do you have a definition somewhere?

Comment: Don't use the SIGNAL/SLOT syntax with modern Qt.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Which method are you referring to? sorry i still dont understand methods.

Comment: `void myOnFinishSlot(QNetworkReply* x);` what do you expect to happen when this method is called?

Comment: Your compiler error output does not match with what your code says. Try cleaning and rebuilding everything.

Comment: Thanks @Botje, I was told to o it that why by another user who answered one of my previous questions. What should i use instead?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I have no idea I was just following the advice given to me in the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69523389/app-closes-before-uploading-data-to-database-qt

Comment: Thanks @Botje, you have helped me numerous times, i will try that now.

Comment: sry I overlooked that you are actually defining the method, just with wrong signature. Note that `void myOnFinishSlot(QNetworkReply* x);` is just a declaration and the error complains about the missing definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your declaration

```
void myOnFinishSlot(QNetworkReply* x)
```

Does not match your definition:

```
void myOnFinishSlot()
```

You effectively defined two methods with different overloads.

Either merge the definition and declaration:

```
public slots:
void myOnFinishSlot(QNetworkReply* x) { exit(); }
```

or move the definition outside of the `class` block:

```
void checkinapp::myOnFinishSlot(QNetworkReply* x) { exit(); }
```

Additionally, don't use the SIGNAL/SLOT notation, since it leads to hard-to-debug errors at runtime. Your `connect` call should be:

```
connect(m_networkManager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &checkinapp::myOnFinishSlot);
```

Comment: Thanks @Botje, I updated my class in the question to what i think you were suggesting. But now I'm getting the error "use of undeclared identifier "QNetworkManager"

Comment: I'm sorry these are probably obvious things one should know but I've been trying to teach myself c++ and only started 2 days ago

Comment: That was a typo, should have been QNetworkAccessManager

Comment: Thanks for the help @Botje, this fixed the error but not the program, The class is still exiting without uploading to the database. 
Original question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69523389/app-closes-before-uploading-data-to-database-qt/69524722#69524722

Comment: Also @Botje, I would highly recommend you put a donation link on your profile. You have commented on or answered nearly every post I've made on stack overflow and I'd be happy to donate to say thanks for all the amazing effort and help.

Comment: You should verify the status code with `x->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute)`. If not 200 inspect the body. I'm fairly confident you forgot to set your firebase API key in the request.

Comment: Thanks @Botje, where would i put that line though?

Comment: The only place where you have access to it, in `myOnFinishSlot`. Use `qDebug() << x->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute)` to print it, for example.

Comment: I implimented that, and still nothing happened. There was nothing in the application output of any new entry in the database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238021/discussion-between-botje-and-silverserpent03).